# Matching and replacing a word whenever a page loads

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I have this code that need to run when my addon starts, needs to look for word and then replace it with different work if it finds it.

```js
var contents=document.body.innerHTML;
var idx=contents.search("hello");
if(idx) {
    contents=contents.replace("hey",'<span id="highlight">hey</span>');
    document.body.innerHTML=contents;
    document.getElementById('highlight').scrollIntoView();
};
```

But I keep on getting error on console

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "resource://jid1-qntppxcxwbpwlw-at-jetpack/lib/main.js", line 5, in 
var contents=document.body.innerHTML;
ReferenceError: document is not defined
```

Answer (score 2):

Judging by the error message you are using the Add-on SDK. Your `main.js` module runs in a separate context - it isn't attached to any window or document. So the variable `document` is not defined of course.

You apparently want to change the contents of web pages - that's what [content scripts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts) are for. You either use [`page-mod`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/page-mod) (it will run the content script for all new pages being opened) or you use [`tab.attach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/tabs#attach%28options%29) to run the content script for existing tabs.

Comment: Looks like URL may've changed: [content scripts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts)

Comment: @DarthContinent: Yes, this answer is old. I've updated the links.

Answer (score 0):

The document is not ready when the code is run. Inside your `body` tag you need to put `onload='ready();'` (or whatever you want to call your function) then define `function ready() { }` in your script, with the code you wrote inside that function.

Comment: This is only main.js file which means I don't have any html code to work or change. This will be addon in firefox that will changes words found in the web page you connecting to.